# How do I selection sort array A to B without copying arrays?

Tags: c, selection-sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
int size;

void SelectionSort(int a[], int size) {
    int i, j, t, min, b[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    printf("\nelements to sort : ");
    for (t = 0; t < size; t++) printf("%d ", a[t]);
    printf("\n\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< selection sort >>>>>>>>>>>>\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[min]) min = j;
        }
        b[i] = a[min];
        printf("\nA ARRAY %d : ", i + 1);
        for (t = 0; t < size; t++) printf("%3d", a[t]);
        printf("\nB ARRAY %d : ", i + 1);
        for (t = 0; t < size; t++) printf("%3d", b[t]);
    }
}
void main() {
    int list[8] = { 69, 10, 30, 2, 16, 8, 31, 22 };
    size = 8;
    SelectionSort(list, size);
    getchar();
}
```

the issue is that whenever the comparing is done the number 2 is copied in the array
what should i do to fix this?

Comment: As long as the input array doesn't contain duplicates, `b[i-1]` is the last number copied, and you should only select a number greater than `b[i-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Each step of the selection sort needs to

1. Identify the least element in the subarray
2. Remove the element
3. Place it at the front

Your code is skipping step 2. So it keeps finding the `2` until `i` increments past it.

Instead of copying into a different array `b`, swap the lowest element with `a[i]`.

```
t = a[min];
a[min] = a[i];
a[i] = t;
```

BTW, it would be helpful in this sort of question to show us the output so potential answerers don't need to compile and run the program themselves.

Comment: I thank you for your comment. But what im trying to do is to not sort A and sort B without copying A int B

Comment: Ok, then you'll still need to remove the minimum element somehow. My only thought is to make a third array of booleans (or 0 and 1) to keep track of which elements have been found. And then the inner loop should start at 0 instead of i+1.

Comment: @0782blessing Why don't you want to copy? I mean, you will have to do a lot of work to guarantee you are doing it right, and you will have to go through the whole array each time, instead of the remaining part. It won't be better than copying (and memcpy is fast). So why? Is it a homework constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of the usual selection sort, that takes duplicates into account.

In each inner loop, the whole array is read. Only values larger than the preceding minimum (`lmin`) are considered, and values equal to the current accepted minimum (`min`) are counted (`nmin` is the count). Then, the array `b` is updated with `nmin` values equal to `min`. The first loop is a special case as there is no preceding minimum.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void selection_sort(int n, int a[n], int b[n]) {
    int j, k, lmin, min, nmin, first;

    min = a[0];
    nmin = 1;
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[j] == min) {
            nmin++;
        } else if (a[j] < min) {
            min = a[j];
            nmin = 1;
        }
    }
    
    for (k = 0; nmin > 0; nmin--) {
        b[k++] = min;
    }
    
    while (k < n) {
        lmin = min;
        first = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] > lmin) {
                if (first) {
                    first = 0;
                    min = a[j];
                    nmin = 1;
                } else if (a[j] == min) {
                    nmin++;
                } else if (a[j] < min) {
                    min = a[j];
                    nmin = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for ( ; nmin > 0; nmin--) {
            b[k++] = min;
        }
    }
}

#define N 20

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 7, 1, 7, 5, 0, 3, 8, 3, 3, 6, 1, 8, 0, 2, 8};
    int b[N];
    selection_sort(N, a, b);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of the boolean `first` is to detect the first accepted current minimum (that is, the first value that is larger than `lmin`).

Another way would be to set `min = INT_MAX` before the beginning of the inner loop, where `INT_MAX` is the maximum `int` value (defined in `limits.h`): we know `lmin < INT_MAX`, otherwise we would already have exited the function. Here is this variant:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void selection_sort(int n, int a[n], int b[n]) {
    int j, k, lmin, min, nmin;

    min = a[0];
    nmin = 1;
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (a[j] == min) {
            nmin++;
        } else if (a[j] < min) {
            min = a[j];
            nmin = 1;
        }
    }
    
    for (k = 0; nmin > 0; nmin--) {
        b[k++] = min;
    }
    
    while (k < n) {
        lmin = min;
        min = INT_MAX;
        nmin = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] > lmin) {
                if (a[j] < min) {
                    min = a[j];
                    nmin = 1;
                } else if (a[j] == min) {
                    nmin++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for ( ; nmin > 0; nmin--) {
            b[k++] = min;
        }
    }
}

#define N 20

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 7, 1, 7, 5, 0, 3, 8, 3, 3, 6, 1, 8, 0, 2, 8};
    int b[N];
    selection_sort(N, a, b);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in this version, `nmin` is set to zero before the inner loop: it doesn't matter if there are values smaller than `INT_MAX`. But if all remaining values are equal to `INT_MAX`, we are going to count them with `nmin++`, so we must start at zero.

Comment: Thank you for your comment . It really helped me